# How to reuse Swift typealias in Objective-C code

Tags: objective-c, swift, react-native-native-module

I'm creating a custom react-native module and I have this custom type in a swift file

**VideoTrimmer.swift**

`typealias TrimCompletion = (Error?) -> ()`

how do I import or reuse it in a file with objective code? Or what's the syntax to redeclare it? I'm not so familiar with Objective-C syntax.

**VideoTrimmer.m**

```
#import "React/RCTBridgeModule.h"
@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(VideoTrimmer, NSObject)
  RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(trimVideo:(NSURL *)sourceURL destinationURL:(NSURL 
  *)destinationURL startTime:(int *)startTime endTime:(int *)endTime 
  completion:(TrimCompletion *)completion)
@end
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Typealiases defined in Swift are [not supported](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-ID53) in Objective-C.
However, you should be able [redeclare](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH8-SW11) the block type in Objective-C with `typedef`:

```
typedef void (^TrimCompletion)(NSError *);
```

Comment: Can you post the Swift equivalent of the Objective-C code you posted.

Comment: @Adrian it's in the question: `typealias TrimCompletion = (Error?) -> Void`